# a translation request

Tags: translation, simplified-characters

I am preparing a toy example for my talk and it would be nice if I had this phrase translated to Chinese (simplified): "the wicked witch of Oz". Also, it would be nice if you could tell me which words in the English version corresponds to which words in the Chinese (simplified Chinese) translation.

Comment: seriously? negative vote?

Comment: You should learn to ask better questions. 伸手党 is usually frowned upon.

Comment: Hey, this is why you're getting negative votes: http://chinese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic **Reason:** "[ ... ] asking for a translation of a word or passage without showing previous effort are not allowed." **Solution:** "We are happy to assist with your translation questions if you are having a specific problem. Please show your attempt at translation in your question and state which area you are having difficulty with."

Comment: I think this policy is right and wrong at the same time. Knowing how to translate from a language to another is not something that you can google/search for. So, no matter how much time I spend online, I will not find a correct translation. Also, I am not asking for a solution to a homework. You can keep voting each others' comments. But that doesn't prove that I am wrong. good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the name "the wicked witch of Oz" may be confusing. Baum's original story has "The Wicked Witch of the East (in Oz)" and "The Wicked Witch of the West (in Oz)".

Oz, or Land of Oz: 奥兹国, 奥茨国、欧茨国、is almost meaningless in Chinese without referencing the common title of the book in Chinese 绿野仙踪

Since the Wicked Witch of the East dies early in the story, your "the wicked witch of Oz" may be understood as

绿野仙踪中的西国邪恶女巫

绿野仙踪: title of the story;
(中): (dative) in...;
(的): (genitive) of...;
西国: the West;
邪恶: wicked;
女巫: witch

Comment: very interesting answer. For me the Oz was enough as I was simply using it as an example to prove my point in a presentation.

Answer (score 1):

奥兹女巫

奥兹(Oz)

女巫(the wicked witch)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a toy you may name it "奥兹女巫手办"

Answer (score 0):

邪恶的（the wicked）女巫（witch）奥兹（Oz）

Please note that Oz is only a name so it has many translation versions, such as 奥子，奥兹.